# How to call route of controller with ajax serialize

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am making an ajax serialize in laravel but I have consulted and have noticed that all of this type ajax call the route from the form :: open, there is no way to call a fixed route? something like this:

```
var formId = '#radicado';

var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    url: ip+'/storeVersion',
    type:  'POST',
    data: $(formId).serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(result){
        $(formId)[0].reset();
        alert(result);
        document.getElementById("version").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("preview").style.display = "none";
        parent.formulario.location.reload() 
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('No se ha actualizado el documento.');
    }
});
```

and the route

```
Route::post('storeVersion','RadicadoController@storeVersion');
```

Comment: Why can't you simply insert a *fixed* URL (`url: 'http://example.com/path/to/method'`) and then route that URL to your controller and handle the data from there?

Comment: Is this javascript being loaded inside of a blade file?  If `/storeVersion` comes after the root, ie `yourapp.com/storeVersion`, you should use relative paths and just set the url to `/storeVersion`.  That way, it will work on any domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `url()` helper method to generate a fully qualified url: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-url

```
...
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
    url: "{{ url('storeVersion') }}", // output http://yourApp.com/storeVersion
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend you to mix javascript with blade code, it's not a good practice. I'll set the `ip` variable with the base url and then construct the url from there.

I based my answer in comments and other answers as I don't understand the question very well.